# React native onTouchMove event not firing

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, touch-event

I am having an issue registering any event on a react-native `Modal` right when another touch event happened which opened the `Modal`.

What I would like to achieve is to capture `onTouchMove` events right after the `Modal` opened without the need to lift my finger again to start the capturing of touch-events from the modal. I would like to create an interaction similar to the long press on the home screen where you could select any item directly after the long press.

[image: home screen interaction]

The (simplified) code I have is as follows:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)

  const toggleModal = () => setModalOpen(!modalOpen)

  const handleTouchMove = () => {
    console.log("moved")
    toggleModal()
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="open modal" onPress={toggleModal} />
      <Modal visible={modalOpen} onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}>...modal content...</Modal>
    <View>
  )
}
```

I have already tried to set to focus with a ref using:

```js
const modalRef = useRef<View>(null);
modalRef.current?.focus() // called inside the toggle
```

or

```js
const reactTag = findNodeHandle(modalRef.current);
AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag); // called inside the toggle
```

Comment: `onTouchMove` should probably be on the button

Comment: you.are.a.god! I would have never guessed this, and it is working perfectly